# localhost redirects me to 404 magento admin panel url

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, magento2

I have successfully installed magento 2 enterprise edition on my local server. It showed me a success page. But when I go to admin panel url it show this error. I am new to magento. The installation took me more than 8 hrs but at the end it crashes.
[image: Below is the error it gives when i go to magento admin panel]

Comment: check if there is .htaccess file on root folder

Comment: yes there is .htaccess file

Comment: is apache rewrite module enabled?

Comment: paster this code in your .htaccess https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emizentech/magento2/master/.htaccess.sample

Comment: Is your localhost working? are you using any web development stack like wamp/xampp ?